# Using string Lists for patterns

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pattern-matching

I want to compare several strings to `s1`.

This is my code:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s1).find();
```

How do I store several strings in  `s2`?

Comment: What exactly you want to compare for? In all strings do you want to check if any one is same as s1?

Comment: Well, lets say I have "ABC" and "bac" in my string list (s2).  Now I want to make an if statement , if s1 contains ABC OR bac . so, my question is, how do I implement a list in the Pattern method?

Comment: Why not just use `s1.contains(someString)` once for each test string? I'm not sure that a regular expression is any more efficient in this case.

Comment: ".contains" doesn't work if some letter in the word is written large. That's why I'm using Pattern matcher and "CASE_INSENSITIVE"

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, you can use `(one string)|(another)`. That said, if s1 changes you might want to pre-build one or more regular expressions and iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this but pattern matcher is not recommendable solution here, as many strings are involved. You can put all strings in a list and check if your list contains s1. Or you can loop through all strings and use pattern matcher to check if any string matches s1.
AFA, contains is case sensitive you can use

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase();
```

This one may be better than regex as regex is always expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: The problem with the normal contains is: its case sensitive. That's why I want to use the pattern matcher.

Comment: _[...] pattern matcher is not recommendable [...] you can [...] use pattern matcher_ - what's the reason for not beeing _recommendable_ and why in the end you suggest just this?

Comment: I don't agree, because You can use

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", "gHi");

This one may be better than regex as. regex is always expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: Edited answer to make it specific to attain the solution here.

Comment: "Can't resolve lang3". And yes, I tried to import "com.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils", it also can't resolve "lang3".

Comment: What shall I do with the .jar file?